# How to create multiple tables in same database using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create multiple tables in the same database called "new", I wonder that can we use php inside the query code to give multiple table names?
Thanks in advance...

```
<?php
$a=0;
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","new") or die("Can not connect to database");
$sql=("create table table.'echo $a++;' ( num int, name varchar(50))");
$con->query($sql);
$con->close();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: that echo for one thing will put a damper on your day. You're also not looping anything with `$a`. - `$a++` to what number and how many iterations?

Comment: php is not recursively embeddable/executable... So, no, you cannot use this code. You cannot make up your own syntax and expect it to "just work"

Comment: It can be made to go into a while loop like while($a<=5) {  }. But the thing is when i execute the above code without iteration, it gives out an error.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$a=0;
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","gcm") or die("Can not connect to database");
$a=0;
while($a<3){
$sql=("create table table". $a ." ( num int, name varchar(50))");
    $a++;
$con->query($sql);
}

//$con->query($sql);
$con->close();
?>
```

Anyhow you have to execute multiple create table SQL statement which i put in a while loop.